# Change value without trigger watch again

Tags: vuejs2

I'm trying to find a workaround to the problem of changing 2-way binding inside a watch of the same property avoiding calling the watch again. for example:

```
<select v-model="language">
  <option ... />
</select>


watch:{
  language(newVal // 'fr' , oldVal // 'en'){
    if(condition){
      // do something
    } else {
      // roll back to the old language
      this.language = "en" // will call watch again.

      // Looking for something like this:
      // Vue.set(this, 'language', 'en', { watch: false })
    }
  }
}
```

I thought about using `@change` but it won't help cause I have to set the value again with an object and not a plain value.

I know I can use other 2-way property and use it as a flag, but I look for something more elegant.

Comment: have you tried doing that in the "beforeUpdate" hook?

Comment: it sounds like `language` should be a computed property which evaluates `condition`

Comment: @Luigi I wasn't aware of this hook! I've already solved it differently but it really good idea to check out. I'll update. If you want to write an answer that does something simple and similar I will accept it as an answer!

Comment: @Dan Actually I solved it by taking out the code and avoiding the watch, then I used a timeout of 100 ms to make the rerender to happen again.

Answer (score 0):

Why roll back the user's selection in the first place? You can use a `computed property` to provide a filtered list of valid options to provide a better user experience.

The example below will only let you select `en` if the condition checkbox is true.

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <p>Condition: <input type="checkbox" v-model="condition" /></p>
      <p>Selection: {{selection}}</p>
      <select v-model="selection">
        <option v-for="opt in filteredOptions" :key="opt.value" :value="opt.value">{{opt.label}}</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  `,
  data: () => ({
    selection: undefined,
    condition: true,
    options: [
      { label: 'English', value: 'en' },
      { label: 'French', value: 'fr' },
      { label: 'Spanish', value: 'es' },
    ],
  }),
  computed: {
      filteredOptions() {
        return this.condition ? this.options.filter(x => x.value === 'en') : this.options;
      }
    }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```